# How to restart a container on docker restart (--restart=true doesn't work)?

Tags: docker, process-management, process-monitoring

I am using docker version 1.1.0, started by systemd using the command line `/usr/bin/docker -d`, and tried to:

- run a container
- stop the docker service
- restart the docker service (either using systemd or manually, specifying `--restart=true` on the command line)
- see if my container was still running

As I understand the docs, my container should be restarted. But it is not. Its public facing port doesn't respond, and `docker ps` doesn't show it.

`docker ps -a` shows my container with an empty status:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                    NAMES
cb0d05b4e0d9        mildred/p2pweb:latest   node server-cli.js -   7 minutes ago                                      0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp   jovial_ritchie      
...
```

And when I try to `docker restart cb0d05b4e0d9`, I get an error:

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot restart container cb0d05b4e0d9: Unit docker-cb0d05b4e0d9be2aadd4276497e80f4ae56d96f8e2ab98ccdb26ef510e21d2cc.scope already exists.
2014/07/16 13:18:35 Error: failed to restart one or more containers
```

I can always recreate a container using the same base image using `docker run ...`, but how do I make sure that my running containers will be restarted if docker is restarted. Is there a solution that exists even in case the docker is not stopped properly (imagine I remove the power plug from the server).

Thank you

Comment: It seems related to this issue: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/6675

Comment: Problably not related to the error, but `--restart=true` is not valid when looking at the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart), what you are looking for is `--restart=always`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, the container flag you're likely looking for is `--restart=always`, which will instruct Docker that unless you explicitly `docker stop` the container, Docker should start it back up any time either Docker dies or the container does.